# Error invoking bsh method: eval.....Sourced file: inline evaluation of:

Tags: jmeter

i need to pass variable(Extracted from response) from one thread to another
Response:"16540$Add373"
i need digits before $
RegEx:
Ref Name:SFID
regex:"[$]
Template:$1$
MatchNo:1

I've used beanshell assertion to set variable in to  jmeter property

${_setProperty(SFID1,${SFID})};

While executing i'm getting

Assertion failure message: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``${_setProperty(SFID1,${SFID})};'' : Attempt to access property on undefined variable or class name

Answer (score 1):

1. Your function is missing underscore
2. Your function is missing comma

Correct syntax is:

```
${__setProperty(SFID1,${SFID},)}
```

I recommend using [Function Helper Dialog](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#function_helper) to generate functions as you can easily get confused with all these round and curly brackets.

Another approach is using `vars` and `props` pre-defined Beanshell variables like:

```
props.put("SFID1", vars.get("SFID"));
```

where:

- vars - is a shorthand to [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance
- props - is an instance of [java.util.Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) class which holds system and JMeter specific properties

See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for extended information on Beanshell scripting in JMeter

Comment: Thank you Dmitri, Vars & Props works for me, but i have failed to use thread1 - ${__setProperty(SFID1,${SFID},)}, in thread2- i've declared ${_property(SFID1)} in http request parameter. i'm not getting value.

Comment: Again missing underscore and comma. Correct one is `${__property(SFID1,,)}`

Answer (score 0):

The answer is - ${__property(SFID1)}. Double '_' after {start.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).